# Prolog determinacy - grouping facts

Tags: prolog, deterministic

I have a fact set as so...

```
fav_fruit(male, young, apple).
fav_fruit(female, young, bannana).
fav_fruit(male, old, bannana).
fav_fruit(female, old, apple).
fav_fruit(female, young, apple).
```

I'm need find out if there is any group of (Gender,Age) where there is more the one favorite fruit (the answer for the facts above would be (female,young.)

What I've been trying to figure out is how to use the `aggregate` or `findall` functions in prolog to return some type of list like....

```
female, young = 2 (apple, bannana)
male, young = 1 (apple)
male, old = 1 (bannana)
female, old = 1 (apple)
```

...that way I could just check the total for each member and test whether it it greater then 1.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
fav_fruit_class(Gender-Age, List):-
  findall(Gender-Age, fav_fruit(Gender, Age, _), LGenderAge),
  sort(LGenderAge, SGenderAge),
  member(Gender-Age, SGenderAge),
  findall(Fruit, fav_fruit(Gender, Age, Fruit), List).
```

The first findall+sort gets a list of classes (Gender/Age). The second findall gets the list of favorite fruits for each class.

Comment: findall/3 + sort/2 -> setof/3

Comment: @Paulo Moura: Not exactly, setof fails with empty result sets, whereas findall+sort does not.

Comment: So? If the findall/3 call above succeeds with an empty list, sort/2 will give, of course, also an empty list, and then the call to member/2 will fail as there are no elements in an empty list. Therefore, you can replace replace the findall/3 + sort/2 calls above with a call to setof/3.

Comment: True, but what i am saying is that findall/3 + sort/2 *is not* the same as setof/3.